# Why does MPI_Iprobe return false when message has definitely been sent?

Tags: mpi

I want to use MPI_Iprobe to test whether a message with a given tag is already pending.

However, the behaviour of MPI_Iprobe isn't quite as I was expecting.
In the example below, I send messages from multiple tasks to a single task (rank 0). Then on rank 0, I wait several seconds to allow plenty of time for the MPI_Isends to complete. Then when I run MPI_Iprobe it returns with flag false. If I repeat after a (blocking) MPI_Probe, then it returns true.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int rank;
  int numprocs;
  int tag;
  int receive_tag;
  int flag=0;
  int number;
  int recv_number=0;

  MPI_Request request;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);

  // rank 0 receives messages, all others send messages
  if (rank > 0 ) {
    number = rank;
    tag = rank;
    MPI_Isend(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request); // send to rank 0
    printf("Sending tag : %d \n",tag);
   } 
   else if (rank == 0) {

   sleep(5); // [seconds] allow plenty of time for all sends from other tasks to complete

   receive_tag = 3; // just try and receive a single message from task 1

   MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,receive_tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&flag,&status);
   printf("After MPI_Iprobe, flag = %d \n",flag);

   MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,receive_tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
   printf("After MPI_Probe, found message with tag : %d \n",receive_tag);

   MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,receive_tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&flag,&status);
   printf("After second MPI_Iprobe, flag = %d \n",flag);

   // receive all the messages
   for (int i=1;i<numprocs;i++){    
     MPI_Recv(&recv_number, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
     printf("Received : %d \n",recv_number);
   }

 }
 MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Gives this output:

```
Sending tag : 4 
Sending tag : 3 
Sending tag : 2 
Sending tag : 5 
Sending tag : 1 
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0 
After MPI_Probe, found message with tag : 3 
After second MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1 
Received : 1 
Received : 2 
Received : 3 
Received : 4 
Received : 5
```

Why does mpi_iprobe return 'false' the first time?

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

EDIT: after the answer by Hristo Iliev I now have the following code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int rank;
  int numprocs;
  int tag;
  int receive_tag;
  int flag=0;
  int number;
  int recv_number=0;

  MPI_Request request;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);

  // rank 0 receives messages, all others send messages
  if (rank > 0 ) {
    number = rank;
    tag = rank;

    MPI_Isend(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request); // send to rank 0
    printf("Sending tag : %d \n",tag);

    // do stuff

    MPI_Wait(&request,&status);
    printf("Sent tag : %d \n",tag);

   }
    else if (rank == 0) {

    sleep(5); // [seconds] allow plenty of time for all sends from other tasks to complete

    receive_tag = 3; // just try and receive a single message from task 1

    MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,receive_tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&flag,&status);
    printf("After MPI_Iprobe, flag = %d \n",flag);

    MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,receive_tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("After MPI_Probe, found message with tag : %d \n",receive_tag);

    MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,receive_tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&flag,&status);
    printf("After second MPI_Iprobe, flag = %d \n",flag);

    // receive all the other messages
    for (int i=1;i<numprocs;i++){   
       MPI_Recv(&recv_number, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }

 }
 MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Sending tag : 5 
Sending tag : 2 
Sending tag : 1 
Sending tag : 4 
Sending tag : 3 
Sent tag : 2 
Sent tag : 1 
Sent tag : 5 
Sent tag : 4 
Sent tag : 3 
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0 
After MPI_Probe, found message with tag : 3 
After second MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using `MPI_Isend` in order to send the messages. `MPI_Isend` *initiates* an asynchronous (background) data transfer. The actual data transfer might not happen unless one of the `MPI_Wait*` or `MPI_Test*` calls has been made on the request. Some MPI implementations have (or can be configured so) background progression threads that will progress the send operation even if no wait/test has been done on the request, but one should not rely on such behaviour.

Simply replace `MPI_Isend` with `MPI_Send` or add `MPI_Wait(&request);` after the former (mind though that `MPI_Isend` + `MPI_Wait` immediately after is equivalent to `MPI_Send`).

`MPI_Iprobe` is intended to be used in busy waits, i.e.:

```
while (condition)
{
   MPI_Iprobe(...,&flag,...);
   if (flag)
   {
      MPI_Recv(...);
      ...
   }
   // Do something, e.g. background tasks
}
```

Real-life message transfers in actual MPI implementations are quite complicated things. Operations are usually split in multiple parts that are then queued. Executing that parts is called *progression* and it is done at various points in the MPI library, for example when a communication call is made or in background if the library implements a background progression thread. Calling `MPI_Iprobe` certainly does progress things but there is no guarantee that a single call will suffice. The MPI standard states:

> The MPI implementation of `MPI_PROBE` and `MPI_IPROBE` needs to guarantee progress: if a call to `MPI_PROBE` has been issued by a process, and a send that matches the probe has been initiated by some process, then the call to `MPI_PROBE` will return, unless the message is received by another concurrent receive operation (that is executed by another thread at the probing process). Similarly, if a process busy waits with `MPI_IPROBE` and a matching message has been issued, then *the call to `MPI_IPROBE` will eventually return `flag = true`* unless the message is received by another concurrent receive operation.

Note the use of *eventually*. How progression is being done is very implementation-specific. Compare the following output from 5 consecutive calls to `MPI_Iprobe` (your original code + a tight loop):

Open MPI 1.6.5 w/o progression thread:

```
# Run 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1

# Run 2
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1

# Run 3
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
```

No consistency between several executions of the same MPI program is observed and in the 3rd run the flag is still `false` after 5 invocations of `MPI_Iprobe`.

Intel MPI 4.1.2:

```
# Run 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1

# Run 2
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1

# Run 3
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 0
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
After MPI_Iprobe, flag = 1
```

Obviously Intel MPI progresses things differently than Open MPI.

The difference between the two implementations can be explained by the fact that `MPI_Iprobe` is supposed to be a tiny probe and therefore it should take as less time as possible. Progression on the other hand takes time and in single-threaded MPI implementations the only point in time where progression is possible is the call to `MPI_Iprobe` (in that particular case). Therefore the MPI implementer has to decide how much is actually progressed by each call to `MPI_Iprobe` and strike a balance between the amount of work done by the call and the time it takes.

With `MPI_Probe` things are different. It is a blocking call and therefore it is able to constantly progresses until a matching message (and more specifically its envelope) appears.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried replacing MPI_Isend with MPI_Send as you suggested, but for some reason the first MPI_Iprobe still returns false. (The same happens if I use MPI_Isend with MPI_Wait)...

Comment: For info, I've added my new code and output in the edit above (in the question).

Comment: `MPI_Iprobe` is intended to be used in busy-wait loops. It might take several calls to `MPI_Iprobe` before the operation is progressed properly. `MPI_Probe` is blocking and therefore it does not return before the operation has been progressed to the point that the message envelope has been received and matched.