# Using MPI_IProbe with MPI_Irecv

Tags: c++, mpi, nonblocking

I have a code for which every processor needs to check to see if it has any messages to receive (possibly multiple messages) and post non-blocking receives for each message. I would like to know what the return value of an MPI_Iprobe will be after an Irecv has been posted, but not yet completed. i.e.:

```
MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, &status);
while(flag)
{
   MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_DOUBLE, &count);
   MPI_Irecv(&Receive_buffer[index], count, MPI_DOUBLE, status.MPI_SOURCE, status.MPI_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Request[index]);
   MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, &status);
}
```

Right now, I believe the MPI_Iprobe is returning true until the MPI_Irecv completes. Is there a way for the probe to move on to any other messages that need to be received? Each process won't know how many messages to check for beforehand so I can't just use several MPI_Probe.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Irecv in this case?  If iprobe tells you the message is available, the Recv should return more or less immediately, which seems like it would simplify reasoning about this. Nonblocking reads and probes have had race conditions in the past (thus, for instance, [MPI_Mprobe](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/mpi-forum-roundup/) ) and I don't see any clear guidance in the standard as to when the Irecv should complete "enough" so that an Iprobe would return false.  (Except after a Wait, in which case you might as well just use Recv).

Comment: Hristo's excellent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20999490/463827) on a related (but not quite duplicate, I think) question is very useful reading for this discussion.

Comment: I use non-blocking sends, non-blocking receives, and a Waitall placed directly after the code I posted. I would like MPI to decide the order in which the messages get received, rather than forcing it to receive in the order it came (using blocking-receives with the Iprobe). 

Slight differences in timing between the processors causes the receives to hang if I use blocking receives (I have tried this). 

I guess a better question is: Is there an MPI function that returns true if a messages needs to be received AND a receive hasn't been posted yet?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be any performance difference between a Recv and an Irecv in this context - the message is already available for receive.  And as Hristo's answer points out, there's no clear cut standard as to when a receive has completed 'enough' to take a message out of contention for an iprobe to return true; indeed, given the wide range of network transports and progress engines that MPI implementations use, it's hard to see how that would even work. On the other hand, MProbe does some of what you want, in that once the message is flagged it won't be flagged again.

Comment: The issue is that the message is ready to be received on the receiving end, but the sender may not be ready (as it's also posting receives or has moved on to doing other work). I'll look into MProbe.

Comment: ? If the probe returns true, it means a message is ready to be received, which necessarily means that a send has at least been posted or initiated.

Comment: A non-blocking send has been posted. But the process that posted it is now busy doing other things. The message is still sitting on the send process needing to be sent, but needs to wait until that process isn't busy to actually send the message.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this actually is a performance issue here?  Are the messages larger than (say) the eager send limit, say, and even if so, is there any data to suggest that actually executing the receives in a different order noticeably changes timings?

Comment: I've profiled the code and have verified this is what is happening. The messages are on the order of 150k doubles, so above the size allowed by eager sends.

Comment: Then it looks like Improbe is the best bet - it doesn't change the behaviour of the Irecvs, but it deals with the interaction between Iprobe + Irecv.