# receiving all the messages at once, parallel MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

I am new at parallel programming and facing following problem ... will be very grateful, if anyone could help me

I have a manager (say processor `M`) and two workers (say processor `A` and `B`). The workers are continuously sending messages to the manager `M`. I want when the manager reaches to the point that he/she needs to read the messages from workers, read all the messages that have been send by each worker. My question is how I can find out how many have been send by each and what should I do to retrieve all of them at once?

For example, I know that worker `A` has send 4 messages (I have counted them when they are sent and received) but the manager starts receiving them one by one if worker `B` has not send anything. (in the code the sends are all asynchronous and I free the handle after sending, on the other hand, each time I receive a message from a worker, I create a new request for it (`request=Irecv()`) that I will use in a `request.Test()` to see if it has arrived and update the request again if I received the data).

Thanks a lot!

Processor `M`, each time solve a mathematical problem, generate a vector of solution. This solution will be immediately send to the all workers (asynchronously). The workers supposed to read all the messages that have been sent to them whenever their cycle reaches to that point whenever appropriate.

Comment: Does [`MPI_IProbe()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Iprobe.html) solve your problem ? See http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node64.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999299/why-does-mpi-iprobe-return-false-when-message-has-definitely-been-sent

Comment: @francis no, it does not ... becasue it is not seeing the messages that have been send from worker A although the worker A has confirmed it has (I dont know why!)