# Asynchronous MPI

Tags: fortran, mpi

I would like to send a MPI message from processor (a) to (b), however, when this occurs depends on processor b.

Let me explain my scenario. Imagine I got two different codes running different time loops. After a time step from each case I need to exchange certain data both ways. Also, I know that e.g. the code associated to processor (a) is running faster than the other (b). Hence, I want to exploit this fact by for example letting processor (a) run the same time loop with the same data as before (Gives better statistics for me). But I need to control it, in the sense that I need processor (a) to run repeated time loops if and only if processor (b) has not finished and updated the data that processor (a) would need to advance in time.

I am currently using MPI_IPROBE in processor (a) after the time loop has finished to check if the data is ready. Although, I have found that even when the data from processor (b) is ready MPI_IPROBE can still give a false flag.

I learnt from the following article that this was not uncommon due to the MPI definition of that library routine.
[Why does MPI_Iprobe return false when message has definitely been sent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999299/why-does-mpi-iprobe-return-false-when-message-has-definitely-been-sent)

**What I have done sofar**

So in the receiver routine I do have a call to mpi_iprobe say 10 times

```
 do i = 1, 10 
     call mpi_iprobe( dest, tag, comm_world, updated, status_, mpierr  ) 
     if(updated)exit
  enddo 

  if(updated) call mpi_recv(buf, size_buf, mpi_real, src, tag, comm_world, status, mpierr)
```

In where I am sending my data I have the following

```
    if(updated)then 
       call mpi_wait( req, status, mpierr) ! this corresponds to the mpi_isend from last time step
       call mpi_isend(buf, size_buf, src, tag, req, comm_world, mpierr)
    else 

       call mpi_request_free(req, mpierr) ! deletes the isend I had  last time
       call mpi_send(buf, size_buf, src, tag, req, comm_world, mpierr) ! the new send
     endif
```

So the idea for me is to free the last isend and make a new one in case it was not received before you completed a new iteration. 
It seems though that my mpi_request_free is doing something unexpectedly. After I have run the code for a bit, and say my processor a is doing 10 iterations per processor b's one iteration, at some point it suddenly drops to a 1 to 1 iteration. This is not expected - and I expect that the mpi_request_free is not doing it right

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you could MPI_Isend from process (b) to process (a) just before the MPI_Recv on (b), and use MPI_Iprobe or similar on (a) to detect that

Comment: That is kind of what I am doing, the problem is that MPI_IPROBE does not always return as true, even though the message has been sent.. I need to loop some iterations over mpi_iprobe in order to make sure I am not missing out an actual update?

Comment: Well strictly all you can check is that there is a message at (a) sent from (b) which is ready to be received. This is not quite the same as (b) has sent a message, though if the difference bothers you I suspect you are doing something rather strange. Why don't you edit your question to tell us what you are really trying to do, there may be a better method than what you propose here.

Comment: I have explained what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: I tried to use mpi_request_free to delete the previous isend, in case it was not received and make another isend. Although, that does not seem quite reliable. Do you know if using such library routine is problematic. I have updated my question. thanks alot