# MPI_Iprobe not setting flag correctly

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I've recently been having trouble with using MPI_Iprobe. I have attached some code below to try and demonstrate the issue (note: the code I'm using is different, the code is purely to create a minimal reproducible example of my issue).

What I want to do is make the process with the rank of 0 send a request message to the process with rank 1. Rank 0 can send this message at an arbitrary point in the loop (hence why I have used an if-statement - `if(i == 1)`). It is possible that rank 0 never sends this message, that's why I'm using Iprobe in `handleReplies()`. Once rank 1 is is done with the loop (which is almost immediate as it has no work to do within the loop), I want it to call `handleReplies()` after five seconds. This is to ensure that the process 0 has used `send()` by the time handleReplies() is called.

The issue is, that when `handleReplies()` is called, it should use MPI_Iprobe to set the `flag` variable to true (ie: 1) as the rank 0 process has sent a message of TAG_REQ. However, for some reason the flag is never set to `1`, and remains `0`. As a result, my MPI_Recv in my rank 0 remains blocked.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, size;
    
    // Call MPI_init, MPI_Comm_rank, MPI_Comm_size...
   
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= 3) {
        if(rank == 0) {
            int fav;
            int linked = 1; // the rank send/recv messages from
            
            if(i == 1) { // at some point in the loop, send a request to the linked process
                printf("Sending msg request to %d\n", linked);
                MPI_Send(&rank, 0, MPI_INT, linked, TAG_REQ, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
           
                printf("waiting for receieve\n");
                MPI_Recv(&fav, 1, MPI_INT, linked, TAG_REP, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                printf("%d's favourite number is %d\n", linked, fav);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
      
    sleep(5); // sleep 5 secs to ensure that the other node is waiting for a reply            
    handleReplies(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1); // before we quit, handle any replies which may be waiting still
    printf("[%d] Finished...\n", rank); 
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
};

void handleReplies(MPI_Comm comm, int debug) {
    int linked = 0;
    int flag = 0; // gets set to 1 if message received
    MPI_Iprobe(linked, TAG_REQ, comm, &flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Is there a requesting message: %s\n", flag ? "yes" : "no");
    if(flag) {
        int recvVal;
        int fav = 11;
        MPI_Recv(&recvVal, 0, MPI_INT, linked, TAG_REQ, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Send(&fav, 1, MPI_INT, linked, TAG_REP, comm);
    }
}
```

Below is the output of my code when I run it with 2 processes:

```
Sending msg request to 1    // shows that message has been sent
waiting for receive  // left hanging as no reply ever sent
Is there a requesting message: no  // 5 seconds after above line (expected "yes" instead of "no")
[1] Finished...
```

after the `[1] Finished...` it continues to hang as `MPI_Send(&fav, 1, MPI_INT, linked, TAG_REP, comm);` because `flag` never gets set to true.

Why is MPI_Iprobe not picking up that rank 0 sent a message five seconds ago?

I have also looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999299/why-does-mpi-iprobe-return-false-when-message-has-definitely-been-sent) but the issue there seems to be that they're using MPI_Isend instead of MPI_Send.

Comment: No, the issue in the linked question is the same as the issue you are having + an `MPI_Isend` that isn't waited on. You must call `MPI_Iprobe` in a loop until it sets the flag to true.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you for your comment. I'll take another read through your answer on that question. Would using MPI_Iprobe inside of a loop until it sets the flag to true  be the same same as using the blocking MPI_Probe method? Also, it is possible that rank 0 won't _always_ send a message, in this case wouldn't that make loop using a while loop inside of `handleReplies()` loop infinitely (as the flag would never be set to true), whereas I would want it to simply just finish if that was the case.

Comment: `MPI_Probe` is blocking - it won't return until there is a message. `MPI_Iprobe` does not block and so allows you to run it in a loop where you do other things while waiting for a message to arrive. But you **have to keep calling it**, otherwise MPI operations won't progress (unless there is an async progression thread, but you cannot rely on it being the case). If you don't want the loop to loop forever, simply send a message with a special tag and terminate the loop upon its reception.

Comment: By the way, the code presented here is flawed because both rank 0 and rank 1 will run `handleReplies()` and since rank 0 never sends to itself, it will remain stuck inside `handleReplies()`.

Comment: @HristoIliev I see, thank you for the suggestions. I've implemented the terminate message technique to quit the loop which seems to be working. Thanks again for your help